# Cannot connect MySQL Server to Netbeans

Tags: mysql, netbeans, mysql-workbench, netbeans-8

I can't connect to my database using the "new connection" option by right-clicking on Databases in the services tab. I get the following error:

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KsUvd.png)

Here is information about the server to help with a solution:

[Server info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ChyIb.png)

[Additional server info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eNEkE.png)

The password I have saved in keychain for the server is "password1" and the connection isn't working even though I entered that.

Comment: If you're using MySQL, why have you tagged SQL server? Is your database really called "ConractSupplier" and not ContractSupplier? If you are giving objects names based on what they are storing, it's important you spell those things properly, to avoid confusion and typographical errors.

Comment: I accidentally tagged SQL server and have removed the tag. The database is called "ContractSupplier" I noticed the picture says "ConractSupplier" but I get the same error message regardless. I have now updated the error image as well.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I finally figured it out. I had to update the MySQL connector driver for Netbeans. I had version "mysql-connector-java-5.1.23-bin" installed and needed to add the new driver "mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar" to match the version of MySQL Workbench that I have.